# prevent time collision in N Course initiation for M Student

Tags: graph-theory, education, collision-detection

Hypothesis: we have `n` courses and `m` students. we decide to initiate a sample course program named `Math123`. how many `Time Unit` do we need to Students **will not** have two different courses at the same time.
**the reason is to prevent time collision.**

Answer (score 1):

If I’m interpreting this correctly, we form the graph on the classes where two classes are adjacent if they have a common student. Then you want to know the chromatic number of this graph.

Comment: yeap and how can I calculate the chromatic number?

Comment: It’s well studied and NP-HARD. This is a special kind of graph, so there may be a different framing that presents a more efficient solution.

Comment: Yeah: on second thought, the original problem is equivalent to finding the chromatic index of an arbitrary hypergraph (students are vertices, classes are edges). I’m sure this is also well studied and hard.

Comment: Dear @Bob Krueger, Thanks a lot. i was wondering to visualize such these problems